# Spring cloud configuration with 2 Spring application on the same server

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-config

I have one spring cloud server that holds all properties files for one application (One for each env).
Now I need to add a new application on the same server. bootstrap.properties file is shared between the 2 applications, therefore spring.application.name is taken by both of my applications with the same value, i.e. both applications use the same properties file.

How do I add a custom property to bootstrap.properties to differentiate between the applications and tell spring-cloud-config to use the appropriate one?